# PHP how to restrict folder and website content to different users?

Tags: php

I've been googling for days now and have come across different ways to secure folders (htaccess, using a PHP page with a password) but these don't tackle my issue.

The problem:
I need to have a site where different clients can access ONLY THEIR content. Client-A needs to be able to access all their Flash content and websites. Client-B and Client-C need to do the same but none of them can access each others content (even by directly linking to it). A username/password system won't work because each client has 400-1000 users and neither myself or the client has time to manage all these users.

I looked into htaccess and htpasswd but I prefer not to use any username/password combo's. Ideally, I'd like a "secret word" or "passphrase" I could pass from an iPad app or Air program to the server to get the content I need. Anyone have some ideas on the best way to handle this?

EDIT: To simplify things... I want to have HTML sites and Flash swf's above my web root and be able to display them to users. How can I make this happen? I have HTML sites that use relative links so using php's readfile() causes these sites to break since those links aren't correct.

Comment: Could you not assign login/password to each client instead of each user?  As long as every user has the same privileges, let them all log in with the same credentials.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing @SurrealDreams

Comment: I want this process to be transparent to users. Clients have several contractors so they don't want contractors to have access after their contracts are up. So if I can limit accessibility to just the software (no user input), that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

What RDBMS are you using ?

With [mod_authn_dbd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) and a basic authentification you would be able to do so.

Something like this,

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Server"
AuthBasicProvider dbd

# core authorization configuration
Require valid-user

# mod_authn_dbd SQL query to authenticate a user
AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM authn WHERE user = %s"
```

Comment: I'd prefer to not have any login forms displayed. I need it to be invisible to the user.

Comment: In this case, the solution suggested by Ispcity might be the best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the software which sends the requests, you could add an own X-header to every request which identifies the user.

With apache_request_headers() you can get your own request header from the request:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

==============

Edit after first comment:

Some code for example:

globals.php

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$key = $headers["X-Authorization-Key"];

$authorized = checkAuthorization($key);
if(!$authorized) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    echo "Access denied!";
    exit;
}

//... db connection or something else to get user specific definitions, paths, ...
//e.g.:
$user = $users[$key];
define("CONTENT_PATH", "/var/www/mypage/data/".$user);

function checkAuthorization($key) {
    //... db connection or something else where the authorization-information are stored in
    //check whether the $key is in the auth-info and return true / false for the result
    return true; //or false
}
```

in every script on top:

```
<?php
require_once("globals.php");
//... work with the user specific definitions, paths
include(CONTENT_PATH."/...");
//...
```

Comment: is this something I can limit via htaccess with a custom header?

Comment: I dont think so, but you could add a function which is called on top of every file which authorize the users  (e.g. in your globals.php which is included on top of every script-file)

Answer (score 0):

What you do is when the user creates their login account, they have the option to select what group they are using. Then when page info is displayed, it displays the normal page, but with the permissions name included in it. You would have to build 3 seperate content pages, but they would only see what the content of their chosen group.

homegroup1.php
homegroup2.php
homegroup3.php

if the user is in group one, the direct would be home"group".php for the display. It would call for the group on the site they go to.